# Change axis labels for plot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, legend

I have a Shiny script that makes a plot with a varying number of lines depending on what is selected in a checkbox. This variable is called "Locus" and has the following options:

- P1_N
- P2_N
- P1_N_RA
- P2_N_RA
- P1P2_N
- P1P2_N_RA

I would like them to be listed in the legend as:

> P1 Normalized
> P2 Normalized
> P1 Normalized, Roll Avg
> P2
> Normalized, Roll Avg
> Avg P1+P2 Normalized
> Avg P1+P2 Normalized, Roll Avg

Any number of these can be selected for the plot based on the shiny script. I've found several ways of changing legend labels but I haven't found any that define which variable goes with which label name so it'll work for my script.

```
loc <- input$locationtoplot1
locus <- input$locustouse #multi-select check box

rep_title <- paste("Locus Info: ", loc, sep = "")
historical.df <- data.frame(filter(data.df, Location == loc,
                                   Date_sampled >= input$startdate, 
                                   Date_sampled <= input$enddate),
                                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

plotdata.df <- select(historical.df, SampleID, Location, Date_sampled, 
               P1_N, P1_N_RA, P2_N, P2_N_RA, P1P2_N, P1P2_N_RA)
                 
plotinfo <- gather(plotdata.df, key = Locus, value = Copies, 
               c(P1_N, P1_N_RA, P2_N, P2_N_RA, P1P2_N, P1P2_N_RA))
mindate <- as.POSIXct(min(plotinfo$Date_sampled))
maxdate <- as.POSIXct(max(plotinfo$Date_sampled))
                 
chartmax <- max(plotinfo$Copies)
plotinfo <- filter(plotinfo, Locus %in% locus)
                 
theplot <- ggplot(plotinfo, aes(x = Date_sampled, y = Copies, group = Locus))+
           theme_classic()+
           geom_line(aes(color = Locus))+
           geom_point(aes(color = Locus))+
           theme(legend.position = "top",
                 axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))+
           scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = input$ticksxaxis, 
                            date_minor_breaks = "1 day", 
                            date_labels = "%Y %b %d")+
           scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,chartmax, by = input$ticksyaxis), 
                              expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0,chartmax))+
           labs(title = rep_title,     
                x = "Date Sampled", 
                y = "Normalized Viral Load")      

plot(theplot)
```

Comment: Try `+ scale_colour_discrete(labels = c(P1_N = "P1 Normalized", P2_N = "P2 Normalized", P3_N = "P3 Normalized", ....))`

Comment: Thank you!!! It's embarrassing how long I tried to do this before asking this question -_-'